# Extra properties of interface as param type of the same interface's method

Tags: typescript, generics, types

I am trying to introduce an API, where you pass object and the object's methods will have `this` typed as the object itself without specifying the type of the object explicitly.

I tried this:

```js
interface BaseProcessor<T> {
    process(this: Readonly<T>): void;
    [key: string | symbol]: unknown;
}

function makeProcessor<T extends BaseProcessor<T>>(definition: T) {
    // code...
}

export const processor = makeProcessor({
    hello: "world!",
    // other possible properties of different types...
    
    process() {
        console.log(this.hello); // <--- this.hello is of type "unknown"
    }
});
```

([Typescript Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgEJwM4QApQPZIYZ5QA8AKgHzIDeAUMo8gA76EYAUYAFsBgFzIAShDgATPCAA2ATwqUAlIIBueYGIDcDJgG0A1hBmCMYKKADmyAD7IMMgLYAjPFIC6ggK4g9IPAHcQLQBfOjoYLwQwYElkezgDXAIIIhIKZAgAD0gQMQw0TBw2ZOIyKkoOMQgYUGAoyUFyBVptRgB6VuQEPEqAOj66ELoukBMWIpSoZABeWPjCpImOeiZkbggpKTxBACI-EikxAEJtgBoW5HbkPB5oFjwiYEcpFFY8Zmgo5KuYZDFgGBg0Ag4GQYBk7wwfR653Or3YHCayxWTGGxGePU25i4vEhaw2eAUGguHVIAFpyaCcT08ZtkHxvqDwShtl4fP4QNtziEgoS6EA))

What I would like to achieve is to have `this.hello` to be of type `string`. Similarly other properties that would be added to the object would be typed on `this` as what their value is, but alter the types slighty (e.g. make them Readonly like in the example provided).

Is it even possible to do that? Any help or suggestions appreciated.

Comment: I'm confused about why you're even trying to do it that way, when `this` would naturally be the type of the containing object anyway, as shown [in this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/wX0Bow). Does that meet your needs? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, please [edit] the question to show a [mre] that motivates your use of `this` parameters.

Comment: @jcalz Thanks for the answer. Well, to be fair, I simplified the question, because what I want is to alter the `this` parameter slightly (more specifically I want to make some properties on `this` readonly). What you suggested works and I didn't knew that, so I though I can simplify this. Thank you anyway for knew knowledge. :) I will edit the question to more suit what I actually want to achieve.

Comment: Still not understanding the motivation for the recursive generic or the `this` parameter, since given the current example I'd do it as shown [in this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/WGbJkm) using the [`ThisType` utility](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#thistypetype), which gives you inference in a way that a `this` parameter does not.  Does *that* meet your needs or am I still missing something?

Comment: @jcalz Thanks, this is actually cool and sufficient for what I intend. Can you please make it a proper answer, so that I can mark it as solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're looking for the compiler to *infer* `this` to be `Readonly<T>` inside your `process()` method, you'll have a better chance of success using the [magical/intrinsic `ThisType<T>` utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#thistypetype), which serves as a way to mark a contextual `this` type.  Then you don't need `BaseProcessor` to be [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html):

```
interface BaseProcessor {
    process(): void;
    [key: string | symbol]: unknown;
}
```

You just need `makeProcessor()` to be generic in a way that tickles `ThisType` correctly:

```
function makeProcessor<T extends BaseProcessor>(
    definition: T & ThisType<Readonly<T>>
) {
    // code...
}
```

And now you get the expected behavior:

```
const processor = makeProcessor({
    hello: "world!",

    process() {
        this;
        // ^? this: Readonly<{ hello: string; process(): void; }>
        console.log(this.hello);
    }
});
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgEJwM4QApQPZIYZ5TIDeAUMtcgA76EYAUAlAFzIBuewAJgNxUaAbQDWEAJ4cMYKKADmyAD7IMEgLYAjPABsAuhwCuIUSDwB3EIIC+FCjGMIwwPCGTq443AQhESAHgAVZAgAD0gQXgw0TBwGX2IoAD4mIWpeCBhQYGdXDmCAMmRAgAtgDECJWgh-ACUIOF5XHQkgpKSKFnI05AB6XuQEPAyAOjGKWwohkBk6eL9SAF53TzifBaZKGmQSiB0dPA4AInMSHV4AQiOAGjtt+nXmLq3tmjAyjEFXmn7kAD0APzId7lDj1RrNVpkHZ7A7SWQKfhzR6sDjcPhI6wdb7UabEHQQEYHeRMEEYEa7fZ4FhfGi2aw0ihAA)